# very long pop-up menu in wxpython

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, wxpython

I have a pop-up menu in a wxPython gui.  The menu works essentially like the simple example on the wiki:

http://wiki.wxpython.org/PopupMenuOnRightClick

However, my menu is really, really long.  As a partial solution, I've organized it using submenus, but in total it contains hundreds of values (yikes).

Here's what I'm wondering.  The way it is currently set up, wxPython has to re-generate the menu from scratch each time the user clicks.  This prevents me from setting up my values as generators instead of lists, which I initially thought would make the menu more efficient. Additionally, it seems like the menu also *must* be destroyed and recreated (using menu.Destroy()) each time the user clicks, to prevent memory problems, so I can't optimize in that way.

Basically, what I really want to know: is there a best practice for optimizing a very large menu in wxPython?

As a side question, I am using a dictionary to contain the menu values.  Should there be any difference if I organize it like this:

```
    d = {'A': [value1, value2], 'B': [value3, value4]}
```

vs. like this:

```
    a = [value1, value2]
    b = [value3, value4]
    d = {'A': a, 'B': b}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me that sounds like it's just bad UI design. You would probably be better off figuring out a different way of displaying the choices. For example, you could put the choices into a custom dialog by subclassing wx.Dialog. Then you can load that up and display it to the user. Instead of destroying the dialog when the user is finished picking an item, you can just hide it. If you want to make it look like a menu, you could put a ScrolledPanel in the dialog and specify its size.

As for your questions about dictionary organization, there is no functional difference in the two methods you mentioned. If you wanted to add items to one of the lists, then it might be slightly more obvious what you're doing with the latter method, but that's about it.